# AddHandler rule for PHP files prompts user to download page instead of processing

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I'm getting an error when I add the following line to my .htaccess file for a server handling PHP scripts:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .php
```

When I try and access a PHP page on my server it goes to a blank page and prompts the user to download the file.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AddType instead of AddHandler.

Example:

```
LoadModule php5_module  /usr/product/php/current/libs/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3
```